# Making bootable USB flash drive from ISO image in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

I need to 'burn' an iso of a bootable dvd (not ubuntu dvd) image onto my USB flash drive.  How can I do it in Ubuntu. In windows I was using [MKBT](http://www.nu2.nu/mkbt/) tool.

I am looking for something like [UNetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/) that can work for any iso.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this article: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

There's a package called usb-creator-gtk (and usb-creator-kde for KDE-desktop).
This application has a GUI to copy an iso to an USB-drive and make it bootable.

Comment: That package is just for Ubuntu. It does not work for any ISO other than Ubuntu. I need to create a Windows 7 bootable.

Comment: I need to create a Windows 7 bootable flash drive from a Windows 7 ISO.

Comment: being a little more specific of that would help - you may want to edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: then you could take a look at this article: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html - it's tested under ubuntu, but it should work on debian too.

Answer (score 1):

there's no universal way to make a bootable usb - as i understand it, unetbootin on linux relies on casper and syslinux, while the windows installer relies on writing the correct bootsector to the drive.

Some sources claim its a simple matter of making a windows 7 iso and running unetbootin on it (which i'm slightly skeptical of, but its worth trying)

Alternately you can copy the files over to the drive and use [ms-sys](http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/) to it with the command - you would likely need to compile and install ms-sys yourself since some repositories don't have it due to potential licencing issues.

```
ms-sys -7 /dev/sdb
```

There's a whole thread of suggestions over at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/6714/how-to-make-a-windows-7-usb-flash-install-media-from-linux) that might help